# One property for multiple buttons

Tags: c#, button, windows-phone-8

Is there a way to write in c# one property for multiple items. e.g. i have 5 buttons, i don't want to write `button1.text = "etc"`, `button2.text = "etc`, I want to write `button.text="etc"` and have button1.text through button5.text to have "etc" text.

Comment: You can make an array.

Comment: If an answer is correct and solves your problem, do accept the your chosen answer so that other community members who shall have the same question will know what worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is feasible with something similar to:

```
public void SetButtonText(string value) {
    this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(b => b.Text = value);
}
```

Or the same through a property:

```
public string ButtonText { 
    set { 
        Controls
            .OfType<Button>()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(b => b.Text = value); 
    } 
}
```

**EDIT**

After a further research, I found out that there are no direct way to access the controls of a page in Windows Phone as I know. So it all depends on whether you wish to get down from the [**PhoneApplicationPage**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.aspx):

As I see it, your solution revolves around the [**Page.LogicalChildren Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.logicalchildren.aspx).

```
public class MyPage : Page {
    public string ButtonText {
        set { 
            LogicalChildren
                .OfType<Button>()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(b => b.Text = value); 
        }
    }
}
```

Since the `LogicalChildren` has a protected accessor, you need to access it through a derived class, which shall be convenient for any kind of page you're working on Windows Phone, I guess.

Or drop a [**Grid**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx) right onto the `PhoneApplicationPage` and then drop other controls over it such as your buttons, then you shall access them through the [**Grid.Children**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

So, having dropped your `Grid` and naming it `myBaseGrid`, one would do the following:

```
public void SetButtonsText(string text) {
    myBaseGrid.Children
        .OfType<Button>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(b => b.Text = "myText");
}
```

I would personally go with the method which name makes it clear what you're doing by spelling the word `Button` in plural as in my sample.

Comment: +1 for the "one line" way of doing this. It might be `Children` instead of `Controls` since its on Phone 8 though

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm surprised they got rid of the `Children` collection and replaced it with `LogicalChildren`. Anyways, still the approach I would use if binding were not an option for some reason.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: I might be wrong. Otherwise, I can't find any `Children` property while browsing the PhoneApplicationPage class on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.aspx

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I think you are right on the "Page" object. The "Panel" objects, which you will have one of as the root "Content" object of the page, still use the `Children` property. So  it depends on if you want to go straight from the `Page` object, or use a `Panel` object first.

Comment: Then, for the OP's question, I would recommend placing a `Panel` control onto the `PhoneApplicationPage` first, then droping other controls over it. Then, the `Panel.Children` property might be useful for the exact same sample as described in my answer.

Comment: I would add one note, `Panel` is a base class. You have to use something like `StackPanel`, `Grid`, or another similar control. Otherwise everything is the same.

Comment: Updated my answer to use a `Grid`. Thanks @BradleyDotNET for your grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for control arrays: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500(v=vs.71).aspx?

Comment: You'd have to iterate over said collection, but otherwise it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign all 5 buttons to the same reference, so that `button.text = "etc"` will work.

You can however, bind the buttons to the same property:

```
<Button Content="{Binding myText}"/>
<Button Content="{Binding myText}"/>
<Button Content="{Binding myText}"/>
<Button Content="{Binding myText}"/>
```

If the binding is set properly with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then all will update when `myText` is updated.

You could also put the controls into a collection and foreach over them to set their `Content` property as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a method that sets them all for you, which you would have to manually write once:

```
public void SetAllButtonTexts(string text)
{
    button1.text = text;
    button2.text = text;
    // . . .
}
```

Alternatively you could use a loop:

```
public void SetAllButtonTexts(string btnText)
{
    foreach (var control in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        (control).Text = btnText;
    }
}
```

And if you don't want to update ALL the buttons, one easy but not-so-elegant thing you could do is modify the `Tag` property of the buttons you want to change with some custom text, and only update those:

```
public void SetAllButtonTexts(string btnText, string tagText = "")
{
    foreach (var control in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()
        .Where(b => string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagText) 
            || (b.Tag != null && b.Tag.Equals(tagText))))
    {
        (control).Text = btnText;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Alternatively the same as my answer, except for the `foreach loop` syntax. It shall work.

Comment: True...I didn't see your answer before I posted. Great minds... :p

Comment: Hehehe... I know that sometimes there are some concurrency over the answers. You probably were writing yours when I posted mine. ;) Great minds nonetheless! =P

Answer (score 0):

In a few words: Group up all your buttons which should get changed in a list. Then later loop through this list and set your text of all buttons.

**Here's some code.**
First of all:

```
public static List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>{};
```

On form_load:

```
buttonList.AddRange(new List<Button>{ button1,button2,button3,...}); // Group your buttons
```

Now it depends on 'when' or 'where' you want to change it. If the buttons should be changed right in the beginning, put the following code into the form_load-event. Else when it should be fired on an event, place it into an event.

```
foreach(Button btn in buttonList)
{
    btn.Text = "Change all button-texts from list at one time.";
}
```

You can also handle multiple lables or boxes etc. like this. Just declare the right datatype.

Greetings